# (Done) Re-Open Being denied bathroom at work because I'm the only male

Tags: discussion, reopen-request

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/120676/being-denied-bathroom-at-work-because-im-the-only-male) was recently closed as off topic.

This is very much a workplace issue and IMO should be re-opened. I took a stab at an edit that will hopefully help make the question a bit clearer.

Comment: I vote to reopen the question. There was no reason to close it. Hopefully the OP will come back to clarify the situation.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere Counterpoint: why reopen the question when the OP has not yet clarified such a crucial aspect of the question?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am hoping adding the definition of light work will atleast help us get it reopened

Comment: I'm really not sure how we can answer this question without knowing at least where the OP is located.

Comment: Looking at chain of events no one asked about location until 2 hours after the question was posted. Its very possible this is just a timezone issue. Either way this is not off topic and should be reopened if it gets closed for another reason, then we can discuss that but this is not off topic

Comment: @SaggingRufus My very first comment asked about location 10 minutes after it was posted.

Comment: @DavidK not sure how I missed that one, its the highest voted comment. I still think it should be reopened. Close reasons should matter. I don't think keeping it closed for a completely different reason is valid

Comment: I don't see how the question is answerable without a lot more input from the OP

Answer (score 1):

The question has been reopened.